# Reproducible documents using base R

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, knitr

I'm working in an environment where I don't have rights to install RStudio.

Would it be possible to automate the report generation using stand alone base R 3.2.0?

Would it be possible to use Markdown / knitR from base R GUI?

Comment: By base R you mean R without and IDE (like RStudio) or a base version of R (say: base R without an IDE and without any additional packages) ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, to your first question: You can automate report generation using stand alone base R, using `Sweave` which has been part of R for about 10 years now. We have been doing this (at ETH Zurich) for teaching purposes for many years now, combining `R CMD Sweave`  with a `Makefile` (and `make`) to produce "everything" (exercises or exams: both the problems and solutions PDFs) from a single `*.Rnw` file.

Now Markdown/knitR  of course needs the `knitr` package, i.e. more than "base R". But you don't need any GUI for that.  We have used Emacs and ESS (https://ESS.r-project.org) for ages for that.